# Serverside implementation of FTP in Java

Tags: java, ftp

I want to build an FTP server that has no actual files in the background. Rather I want the files uploaded to it being immediately processed by my backend. The file listing of the upload directories should contain those files that are not yet processed. Deletion or moving should not be possible.

Also, on the download side I want to present those files that I'm able to deliver. But files shall be created - again by the backend - on demand.

Since I don't want to reimplement FTP, *does anyone know a Java library that helps implementing the server side of the FTP protocol*, that is customizable as I need it to be?

I have looked into the always helpful Jakarta Commons but they seem to focus on the client side.

Thanks
Mike
[;-)

Comment: Why the requirement for FTP? It's just that there's a lot more available for this kind of thing if you were to use HTTP.

Comment: Like always when you build something new it must look as if nothing has changed. (And there is an existing service used by many parties.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check out http://mina.apache.org/ftpserver/.

> The Apache FtpServer is a 100% pure Java FTP server. It's designed to be a complete and portable FTP server engine solution based on currently available open protocols. FtpServer can be run standalone as a Windows service or Unix/Linux daemon, or embedded into a Java application. We also provide support for integration within Spring applications and provide our releases as OSGi bundles.
>
> The default network support is based on Apache MINA, a high performance asynchronous IO library. Using MINA, FtpServer can scale to a large number of concurrent users.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can use [Apache FtpServer](http://mina.apache.org/ftpserver/).

`The Apache FtpServer is a 100% pure Java FTP server. It's designed to be a complete and portable FTP server engine solution based on currently available open protocols. FtpServer can be run standalone as a Windows service or Unix/Linux daemon, or embedded into a Java application. We also provide support for integration within Spring applications and provide our releases as OSGi bundles.`

Answer (score 1):

Above mentioned links to Java FTP Server doesn't work because they have been moved to below:

http://mina.apache.org/ftpserver-project/index.html

Comment: Thank you very much for that info, but you should have commented the other answers instead. SO FAQ says: "Improve posts by editing or commenting"

Comment: @DerMike Thank you for the suggestion..but then I have to edit three posts and place a comment on every post?? Flood of comments to every post which I would not like to do myself. Also creating more work for others to come and review what edits I have made...ofcourse I am editing their answers...

Answer (score 0):

Here's a couple which might be helpful:
http://drftpd.org/
http://mina.apache.org/ftpserver/

Since you do not actually want the files to be transfered and listed in a usual FTP behaviors, you'll need to intercept the codes of how the files are listed and retrieved by the clients.