# FTP Look a like application in java/HTML

Tags: java, html, jsp, web-applications

What would be a better approach to develop a FTP look a like application as the one shown below .

It would allow people in my project to download all the software installables we use , like **IBM Websphere (1 GB)** , **eclipse (500 MB)** and lot's of other software ranging from 2.5 GB to 500 MB individual size which are hosted in Red Hat Linux

1. Is it better just install Apache HTTP Server and set the DocumentRoot to the source directory and Apache do the rest?

   ```
   DocumentRoot "/hosting/softwares"
   ```

[image]

2. **Write a simple JAVA/J2EE web application using HTML/JSP** to generate view like above and with pseudo code likw below .But i think its not good idea to read such huge files in JAVA.

   ```
   File downloadFile = new File(filePath);
   FileInputStream inStream = new FileInputStream(downloadFile);

   response.setContentType(mimeType);
   response.setContentLength((int) downloadFile.length());


   String headerKey = "Content-Disposition";
   String headerValue = String.format("attachment; filename=\"%s\"",  downloadFile.getName());
   response.setHeader(headerKey, headerValue);

   // obtains response's output stream
   OutputStream outStream = response.getOutputStream();

   byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];
   int bytesRead = -1;

   while ((bytesRead = inStream.read(buffer)) != -1) {
       outStream.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
   }

   inStream.close();
   outStream.close();
   ```

**Is there any other approach to get this done , like using HTML or any other framework.**

Comment: Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2302050/serverside-implementation-of-ftp-in-java.

Comment: How is this offtopic?

Answer (score 2):

If your files are 100% static and served from disk, then Apache is the easiest and most efficient choice. You can still provide static `index.html` files to improve navigation and look-and-feel.

A wiki provides the extra benefit of easy secured file upload as well. You should look into wikis, but setup is more complex that Apache.

A webapp server (servlet/JSP, J2EE, .NET, ...) is not really relevant, because they are intended for dynamic content. They can of course serve static content, but it's overkill to use for your purpose, unless your files need to be stored in a database, instead of the file system.