# Apache DocumentRoot Configuration

Tags: apache, apache2, httpd.conf, rhel, apache2.4

I have Apache HTTP server installed in one of our RHEL6 Box.

```
Server version: Apache/2.2.15 (Unix)
Server built:   Jul 18 2014 02:31:29
-D DYNAMIC_MODULE_LIMIT=128
 -D HTTPD_ROOT="/etc/httpd"
 -D SUEXEC_BIN="/usr/sbin/suexec"
 -D DEFAULT_PIDLOG="run/httpd.pid"
 -D DEFAULT_SCOREBOARD="logs/apache_runtime_status"
 -D DEFAULT_LOCKFILE="logs/accept.lock"
```

I just need to provide an FTP kind of page which allows downloading of the files hosted in the `DocumentRoot` directory.These are the lines i have modified in the `httpd.conf`.
When i enter the host name instead of listing all the directories in the DocumentRoot /hosting/apps/software-packages it is displaying the below test page.
But i can access the sub directories of DocumentRoot  though URL , like shown in the below screen.

```
DocumentRoot "/hosting/apps/software-packages"

#
# Each directory to which Apache has access can be configured with respect
# to which services and features are allowed and/or disabled in that
# directory (and its subdirectories). 
<Directory />
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
</Directory>

<Directory "/hosting/apps/software-packages">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None

</Directory>
```

[image]

[FTP Look a like application in java/HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33071099/ftp-look-a-like-application-in-java-html)

[image]

Furthermore there are no html files in var.

```
$ l
total 16
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Jul 18  2014 html
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Jul 18  2014 cgi-bin
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 4096 Oct 12 06:44 error
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 4096 Oct 12 06:44 icons

DIR=/var/www
$ l html/
total 0

 DIR=/var/www
```

Answer (score 1):

change
    Options FollowSymLinks
to  be
    Options FollowSymLinks  Indexes